# perl language pointer

Tags: perl

Can You please confirm me the  how the below command will work or purpose of this type of statement.

```
           $layermap{@myline0[1]}=$myline[1];
```

Thanks & Regards
Madhvi

Answer (score 4):

Let's dissect `$layermap{@myline0[1]}=$myline[1];`

`%layermap` is a hash (an unordered map, or an associative array, or a dictionary, if you're coming from other languages with different nomenclatures).  `$layermap{KEY}` is one element of the hash.  This element can have a value.

`@myline0` and `@myline` are arrays.  `$myline0[1]` and `$myline[1]` are each the second element of their respective arrays.  These elements can hold a value.

`@myline0[1]` is a sloppy way of writing `$myline0[1]` (it works, because it's a single-element slice).

So your line of code assigns a value to the element in the `%layermap` hash with a key derived from the value of `$myline0[1]`.  The value assigned is the value held in the `$myline[1]` of the array `@myline`.

Answer (score -1):

The `$layermap` variable is a hash (dictionary) object, `@myline0[1]` is an array and seems to provide the key value,  `$myline[1]` is an array reference and provides the value.

Comment: There are several inaccuracies here.  `$layermap` is not a hash, as written it's a scalar.  `$layermap{somekey}` is a hash element, and `%layermap` is a hash.  `@myline0[1]` is not an array, it's a single-element array slice.  `$myline[1]` is not an array reference, it's an array element.